# How to simple view second screen on first screen on WIndows 10?

Tags: windows, display, remote, lcd, pip

I have two LCD monitors plugged in one PC with Windows 10.
First monitor is main and it's placed next to PC with keyboard and mouse.
Second monitor is in another room.
And while I'm on first monitor it's imposible to see what is displayed on second monitor. I need to have view on my first monitor what is on second monitor.

**Is there anything like PIP (picture-in-picture) but for monitors in Windows 10?** Like "MIM" (monitor-in-monitor) :) ?
I need something simply. Something like, start program, make one or two clicks and you will see what you need.
I've tried OBS Studio and it makes what I needed but for some other people **OBS is too complicated**. I need something easier for handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions by myself and it was easier than I thought.

- first solution is to use Windows magnifier.
  [Screenshot - magnifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4TN5.jpg)
- second is to use VLC player or another player which allows you to record/play screen.
  [Screenshot - VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVZdE.jpg)

For VLC I made simple BAT file:

```
@echo off
set vlcPath="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
start "" %vlcPath% %1 screen:// --screen-fps=25 --screen-width=320 --screen-height=240  --video-on-top --qt-minimal-view --no-video-deco --screen-follow-mouse --screen-mouse-image=aero_arrow.png  --mouse-events --nooverlay --video-x=0 --video-y=0 --play-and-exit
Exit
```

Mouse icon (--screen-mouse-image=aero_arrow.png) must be placed in same folder as vlc.exe, or just define your own directory.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the possibility to use VLC.
I'm using this daily now and it works wonderfully.

For reference, I use these additional parameters in my bat file

`--live-caching=0
--screen-left=3440
--screen-width=1920
--screen-height=1080`

This skips over my left screen (3440 PX wide) and only displays the second screen (Full HD).
Also, it removes the delay caused by VLC caching the capture.